# How to add column in sales_order_grid also want to get that attribute from sales_order collection?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, sales-order, order-grid

I want to a column in `sales_order_grid` I successfully did that but I also want to `get` my custom attribute from `sales_order` collection because I want to set value on some action, my problem is a can't get that attribute...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do that:

**Step 1**

First of all it's better to make you own custom module make `app/code/[Vendor]/[Module]/registration.php` also `app/code/[Vendor]/[Module]/etc/module.xml`.

**Step 2**

Add your custom column in `DB` mine is `custom_print_status`, also I made an `UPDATE` script to set default value in my custom attribute in all existing orders, so create `app/code/[Vendor]/[Module]/Setup/InstallData.php`

```
<?php
namespace [Vendor]\[Module]\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Sales\Setup\SalesSetupFactory
     */
    protected $salesSetupFactory;
    protected $_resourceConnection;
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Setup\SalesSetupFactory $salesSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Sales\Setup\SalesSetupFactory $salesSetupFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection  $resourceConnection

    ) {
        $this->salesSetupFactory = $salesSetupFactory;
        $this->_resourceConnection = $resourceConnection;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context) 
    {
        $installer = $setup;

        $installer->startSetup();

        $salesSetup = $this->salesSetupFactory->create(['resourceName' => 'sales_setup', 'setup' => $installer]);

        $salesSetup->addAttribute(Order::ENTITY, 'custom_print_status', [
            'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
            'length'=> 11,
            'visible' => false,
            'nullable' => false
        ]);

        /* UPDATE CUSTOM PRINT STATUS TO 'No' By PartbSaif */
        $updateData = array('custom_print_status' => 0);
        $connection = $this->_resourceConnection->getConnection();
        $connection->update(
            $connection->getTableName('sales_order'),
            $updateData
        );
        /* ========================================= */

        $installer->endSetup();
    }
}
```

**Step 3**

Add your custom column in `sales_order_grid`, create `app/code/[Vendor]/[Module]/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_grid.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="sales_order_columns">
        <column name="custom_print_status" class="[Vendor]\[Module]\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\CustomPrintStatus" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select">
            <settings>
                <filter>select</filter>
                <options class="[Vendor]\[Module]\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\CustomPrintStatus\Options"/>
                <dataType>select</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Print Status</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

**Step 4**

For render your custom column from `sales_order` table. e.g 0/1 in `sales_order_grid`, create `app/code/[Vendor]/[Module]/Ui/Component/Listing/Column/CustomPrintStatus.php`

```
<?php 

namespace [Vendor]\[Module]\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;

use \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use \Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;
use \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder;
use \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection;

class CustomPrintStatus extends Column
{
    protected $_orderRepository;
    protected $_searchCriteria;
    protected $_resourceConnection;

    public function __construct(
        ContextInterface $context, 
        UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory, 
        OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository, 
        SearchCriteriaBuilder $criteria,
        ResourceConnection  $resourceConnection,
        array $components = [], 
        array $data = [])
    {
        $this->_orderRepository = $orderRepository;
        $this->_searchCriteria  = $criteria;
        $this->_resourceConnection = $resourceConnection;
        parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
    }

    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {  
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {
                $order = $this->_orderRepository->get($item['entity_id']);
                $customPrintStatus = $order->getCustomPrintStatus();
                $item['custom_print_status'] = $customPrintStatus;
            }
        }

        return $dataSource;
    }
}
```

**Step 5**

In `DB` value will store as 0 and 1 e.g 0 => 'No' & 1 => 'Yes', so to show value as Yes/No, create file.
`app/code/[Vendor]/[Module]/Ui/Component/Listing/Column/CustomPrintStatus/Options.php`

```
<?php

namespace [Vendor]\[Module]\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\CustomPrintStatus;

class Options implements \Magento\Framework\Option\ArrayInterface
{
    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        $options = [
            [
                'value' => 1,
                'label' => __('Yes')
            ],
            [
                'value' => 0,
                'label' => __('No')
            ]
        ];

        return $options;
    }
}
```

**Step 6**

BTW when you try to filter value in `sales_order_grid`, you'll get an error, to do that you have to map your value in `Order Grid Collection`, to do that you have to override `Collection` file of Order Grid, create file
`app/code/[Vendor]/[Module]/etc/di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
     <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
         <arguments>
             <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="sales_order_grid_data_source" xsi:type="string">[Vendor]\[Module]\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid\Collection</item>
             </argument>
         </arguments>
     </type>
</config>
```

`app/code/[Vendor]/[Module]/Model/ResourceModel/Order/Grid/Collection.php`

```
<?php

namespace [Vendor]\[Module]\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid;

use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid\Collection as OriginalCollection;

/**
 * Order grid extended collection
 */
class Collection extends OriginalCollection
{
    protected function _initSelect()
    {
        $this->addFilterToMap('created_at', 'main_table.created_at');
        $this->addFilterToMap('increment_id', 'main_table.increment_id');
        $this->addFilterToMap('base_grand_total', 'main_table.base_grand_total');
        $this->addFilterToMap('grand_total', 'main_table.grand_total');
        $this->addFilterToMap('store_id', 'main_table.store_id');
        $this->addFilterToMap('billing_name', 'main_table.billing_name');
        $this->addFilterToMap('shipping_name', 'main_table.shipping_name');
        $this->addFilterToMap('status', 'main_table.status');
        parent::_initSelect();
    }
     protected function _renderFiltersBefore()
     {
         $joinTable = $this->getTable('sales_order');
         $this->getSelect()->joinLeft($joinTable, 'main_table.entity_id = sales_order.entity_id', ['custom_print_status']);
         parent::_renderFiltersBefore();
     }
}
```

**Step 7**

Now to set value as `No` when new order created you have to make `event` called `sales_order_save_before`, so create
`app/code/[Vendor]/[Module]/etc/event.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="sales_order_place_after">
        <observer name="set_order_attribute" instance="[Vendor]\[Module]\Observer\SetOrderAttribute"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

`app/code/[Vendor]/[Module]/Observer/SetOrderAttribute.php`

```
<?php
namespace [Vendor]\[Module]\Observer;

class SetOrderAttribute implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return $this
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order */
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        $order->setCustomPrintStatus(0);
        return $this;
    }
}
```

**Step 8**

For set value on in `DB` for your custom column, add below code in `Model`, this code set `1` value on action.

```
            /* CHANGE PRINT STATUS TO 'Yes' By PartbSaif */
            $yes = 1;
            $order->setCustomPrintStatus($yes)->save();
            /* ========================================= */
```

**Explanation**
What this module does ?

I want to create column in `sales_order_grid` column name is `custom_print_status`, when user select order and click on `Print Invoices` Or `Print All` under `Action` drop-down, the `custom_print_status` changed to `Yes`, otherwise it's value is by default set to `No`, for set value to `Yes` on above 2 action you need to override `/[root]/vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Invoice.php`, I hope you know how to override `Model` file from vendor, if not refer to this link => [How to override Model file](https://magenticians.com/override-model-magento-2/)

In this file you'll find `getPdf()` function, put above code at the end of `foreach` loop like this:

```
        foreach ($invoices as $invoice) {
             /* Code to set value */
        }
```

Thank You.